# Make posts automatically from an Online XML file through wp cron job

Tags: wp-cron, xml

I want to import posts from a RSS feed using the WP Cron API. Here is the link to [the XML Feed](http://www.propspace.com/feed/xml.php?cl=1371&pid=8245&acc=8807).

I activated different Feed Aggregator wordpress plugin but it gives error.

```
Problem:
FeedWordPress encountered the following error when trying to retrieve this feed:
A feed could not be found at http://www.propspace.com/feed/xml.php?cl=1371&pid=8245&acc=8807. This does not appear to be a valid RSS or Atom feed.
If you think this is a temporary problem, you can still force FeedWordPress to add the subscription. FeedWordPress will not be able to find any syndicated posts until this problem is resolved.
```

A guy told me to write a php code to update the values in MySQL and then call in WP. I have no clue with this.

Comment: _"to put it work on urgent basis"_ doesn't help to get an answer quicker. What has been your research so far? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. More info about how to ask a good question can be found on the [ask] page.

Comment: Thnx Kaiser, I will update it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured a way. There is a WP ALLIMPORT plugin. Here is the link if anyone else need help [Download wpallimport plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/)